# QGIS Atlas I want a second map as Overview but not have it on every other page when i print it to pdf

Tags: qgis, atlas

I'm working with QGIS Atlas and I'm showing in my "map1" a polygon layer that jumps through 24 different polygons.
Now I want to add a second or third map (maybe more depending on the polygon layer) that shows an overview of the polygon layer.
My problem is that when I print or export to PDF it prints the second map on every other page.
I was wondering if there was another option than doing a second atlas and combine the two PDFs.

Comment: This sounds like a Report would be more suited to your needs. Have a look at this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AonZWxDA-cc

Comment: That seems very interesting i will try it out thanks for the suggestion

Comment: If the Report feature works for you, would you be willing to post an answer explaining how you used it? There aren't a lot of examples of how people use this feature.